# How to find number of different elements in sorted array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

How to find number of different elements in sorted array with O(1)?
Using in C++, multimap container (STL).
I mean O(1) exactly.

Comment: I think you mean O(n), O(1) would require prescience unless you tracked this as you added/removed elements to/from the array and, then, you're not really "finding" it so much as just returning it.

Comment: You can't because you don't know how many of the entries share the same key. If you're using a plain map, the number of unique entries is the number of keys, but in a multimap (which isn't the same thing as an array, btw), you can have any number of entries that share the same key.  I assume by "different elements" you really mean "different keys" but the problem is the same if you're talking actual elements and don't have something else enforcing that an element isn't stored twice.  If you do, then the answer is the number of entries.

Comment: @tvanfosson That looks like a proper answer to me.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - I was in the process of writing a more extensive explanation.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really possible to know in constant time how many unique items are in a collection, even if the collection is sorted, unless you only allow one instance of the item in the collection at any given time.  If you do restrict the collection to only having unique items, then the answer is trivial; it's the number of items in the collection since they all have to be distinct.

In the case where you have an ordered collection of non-distinct items, you can find the number of distinct items by iterating through the collection and finding the state changes (when the current value isn't the same as the previous one).  The number of distinct items is one more than the number of state changes (or the number of state changes if you start with the "empty" state and count the first item as a change from that).

You can also augment your data structure and add/delete algorithms to track the number of distinct items in the collection so that you can "find" the this number in constant time by simply querying a value that is updated during add/delete.  This shouldn't affect the efficiency of either since you only need to determine, on add, whether the new item is the first of it's type by checking if the prev/next item has the same key and, on delete, whether the removed item is the last item of its type, by the same check.

Let's consider a simple illustration.

Let's say you have a magic bag containing several different colored blocks numbered from 1 to N.  The bag is magic because whenever you reach into the bag you can either determine how many blocks are in the bag (the value of N) OR look at a block with the guarantee that each time you reach into the block you get the next block in color order, all the reds, all the greens, etc. until no more are left OR you can examine any single block by its number.  What you want is to find out how many different colors of blocks are in the bag by reaching into the bag some fixed number of times.

Now, getting the number of total blocks in the bag takes one reach but does you no good because you want to know the number of different colors.  Getting any fixed number of randomly selected blocks (less than N) takes a fixed number of reaches but does you no good because they don't tell you anything about the rest of the blocks in the bag.  The only thing you can do is pull all of the blocks out one by one in order and find the number of times that the next block is a different color from the last one.

Now if you allow me to change how I put blocks into or take them out of the bag, I could keep track of how many colors of blocks are in the bag as I go, then it again becomes trivial to tell you.  I just give you the value that I'm keeping track of. Essentially I'm trading a small amount of space (the place where I keep track of the value) and a bit extra time during add/delete for a larger amount of time trying to find the number of distinct colors later.  You just need to decide if the trade-off is worth it.